# Error in model.frame.default(formula = SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) + : invalid type (list) for variable 'ti(LOC_X)' using R gam

Tags: r, list, dataframe, gam, mgcv

I have the following dataframe:

```
PLAYER_ID,PLAYER_NAME,LOC_X,LOC_Y,SHOT_MADE_FLAG
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-20,19,0
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-29,168,1
1627759,Jaylen Brown,7,30,1
1627759,Jaylen Brown,9,6,0
1627759,Jaylen Brown,-176,186,0
```

And I am trying to use this code on it (this is using the mgcv package, NOT tis):

```
league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) + 
                         ti(LOC_Y) + 
                         ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y),
                       data = shots)
```

But when I do so, I get:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'ti(LOC_X)'
```

I am not super experienced in R, what can I do to solve this issue? I tried putting in:

```
ti(unlist(LOC_X))
```

but that caused the exact same error. I could really use some help on this one.

Edit - added output of search(). Also added full code below:

```
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "package:gam"      
 [4] "package:foreach"   "package:splines"   "package:mgcv"     
 [7] "package:nlme"      "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
[10] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
[13] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[16] "package:base"
```

Code:

```
library('mgcv')
library('gam')
library('dplyr')

shot_df <- read.csv("Jaylen Brown holder_shot_chart.csv")
shots <- subset(pass_df, !(is.na(LOC_X)))

league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) + 
                         ti(LOC_Y) + 
                         ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y),
                       data = shots)
```

Comment: It looks like you have another package loaded that provides a `ti()` function and it is that function that is being found not the `mgcv::ti()` one. Can you add the output from `search()`, called after you get this error, to your question please?

Comment: Output added. I will add, though, that mgcv::ti() produces the same error. I also added my full code, if that helps, but I doubt that it will.